# How to send response before the file is uploaded using express file upload

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, upload

I have a NodeJS application where users upload files to the server. Some users may be restricted from uploading files. So I need to check this on the server side and send the appropriate response to the client.

The **problem** is that if the user is restricted, the entire file is uploaded first and then the restriction response is sent to the client, which causes a waste of Internet traffic. Is there a way to check this before uploading the file?

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
const C = require('../../config').consts

const app = express();

const httpServer = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/exmaple.com/privkey.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("/etc/letsencrypt/live/exmaple.com/fullchain.pem")
}, app);

httpServer.listen(process.env.PORT);

app.use(fileUpload({ limits: { fileSize: C.MAX_FILE_SIZE, }, abortOnLimit: true, }));

const uploadFile = async (req, res) => {
    try{
        let files = req.files;

        if (isRestricted()){
            return res.status(403);
        }

        saveFile(files);

        return res.status(200);

    } catch (err){
       return res.status(500);
    }
}

app.post('/uploadFile', uploadFile)
```